# Get action value from current form to jquery autosave

Tags: jquery, forms, autosave

How do I get URL to be the "`action`" value from the form I am submitting?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/outprojects/save_at/10232" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_10232" method="post">
```

So I want jQuery autosave to save to this action URL (however it defaults to the current URL).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$("form").autosave(
{
  callbacks: {

    scope: 'all',
    trigger: ["change", function() {
      var self = this;
      $("[name=save]").click(function() {
        self.save();
      });
    }],
    save: {
      method: "ajax",
      options: {
        type: 'PUT',
        url: this.getAttribute('action')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

});

Gives the error:

TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: How about `$(this).attr("action");`

Comment: This gives the error_ SyntaxError: missing } after property list url: $(this).attr('action');_

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
            scope: 'all',
            trigger: ["change", function () {
                var self = this;
                $("[name=save]").click(function () {
                    self.save();
                });
            }],
            save: {
                method: "ajax",
                options: {
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: $(this).attr('action')
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This gives the error _SyntaxError: missing } after property list url: $(this).attr('action');_

Comment: Using _url: $("form").attr('action')_ works, however with several forms in the same page there are several call actions going so I need it to be some variant of this to only save that form (I think?).

Comment: Now there is no error message, but it submits to the current page and not the page that is within "admin".